# Facebook like notification updates using django signal or notification

Tags: django, django-signals, django-notification

How can i use django-notifications or django-signals to make something like facebook updates notification that shows in the user profile if any other user likes or posts comments on user's blog or posts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the activity feed, we use https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream Documentation: http://justquick.github.com/django-activity-stream/

For the js widget and live notifications, we use https://github.com/subsume/django-subscription yourlabs example, it depends on redis but you can easily add a model backend if you really want to. Redis is a good choices it's half a megabyte of dependency. Documentation: http://django-social.rtfd.org

There is no application that does meta-notifications ("notification groupping") properly but a lot of research has been done. Basically you need another app, with a MetaNotification model, and something (management command, signal ...) that will visit notifications and create MetaNotification instances. Then you should display MetaNotification lists rather than Activity or notification list.

Finnaly, if you want configurable email notifications then you can use django-notifications: https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification or this app which looks nicer: http://www.tomaz.me/django-notifications/

I'm not aware of any app that does it all. It *is* going to be some work for you.

"It's a long way to the top if you wanna rock'n'roll" or as I like to say "patience and perseverance" :)

Comment: @jpic: I have used `django-notifications` for email notifications and it works good, but I am having some trouble with `django-subscription` In the documentation they have have said we can either use yourlabs example or go for the `bare` installation but for the `bare` installation there is no documentation at all. Is it necessary for us to use the `yourlabs example`

Comment: I've left my IRC contact at the top of the documentation, contact me and help you and fill the blanks in the documentation at the same time: 
http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-subscription-yourlabs/en/latest/yourlabs.html

Comment: I am really sorry to sound like a novice, but I do not know how to get across to you using IRC.

Comment: Short answer: Yes it is necessary to use the yourlabs example. Because the bare doesn't have sufficient features to have a facebook-ish live notifications widget. All you have to do is use the webchat: http://webchat.freenode.net . You will also need a registered account for private messaging to work on freenode. Once connected with the webchat, start following this tutorial at step 2: http://www.wikihow.com/Register-a-User-Name-on-Freenode It's a really good deal because it will enable you to access #django and #python and many other Open Source support channel.

Comment: Here is similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602951/how-to-use-django-subscription-to-create-live-notifications

Comment: @jpic: This is an awesome app, but its really hard to understand without proper documentation. Please add some more to documentation and about how can i integrate it with my apps. Thank you.

Comment: Well it's a long way and it's hard. You need patience and perseverance. You should follow me on github, i added a lot of documentation this morning. Mostly technical, i intend to write a tutorial later today.

Comment: for emails/sms notifications, I would recommend django-herald as it has some nifty features which could really boost productivity and code debugging.

Comment: @jpic I also wanted to mark notification as `read` from `unread`. Have you implemented something like that?

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedly allows you to build newsfeed and notification systems using Cassandra and/or Redis. Examples of what you can build are applications like the Facebook newsfeed, your Twitter stream or your Pinterest following page.